# mongo bson objectid

Tags: mongodb, bson

curious what the `BSON::ObjectId.id.data` array represents?

for example `[77, 145, 20, 13, 225, 96, 124, 5, 31, 0, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BSON::ObjectId.id.data` represents 12 bytes of objectId.
 Here's what exactly each byte mean:

```
0123   456     78   9 10 11
 ^^     ^^     ^^     ^^
time  machine  pid    inc
```

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value
>   consisting of a 4-byte timestamp
>   (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte
>   machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a
>   3-byte counter. Note that the
>   timestamp and counter fields must be
>   stored big endian unlike the rest of
>   BSON. This is because they are
>   compared byte-by-byte and we want to
>   ensure a mostly increasing order.

[ObjectId documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)